# Eror in c code: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘free_node_t’

Tags: c, list, struct, operating-system

`.h` file with header for creating a list in `c`:

```
 #ifndef SO605_GC
 #define SO605_GC
 #include <stddef.h>

 #define MEMSIZE 4096*1024*1024          

 typedef struct free_node {
     size_t size;
     struct free_node *next;
 } free_node_t;

 typedef *free_node_t mem_free_t;

 void *aloca(size_t size);
 void libera(void *ptr);

 #endif
```

When I compile the error occurs:

> aloca.h:14:10: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘free_node_t’ 
>   typedef *free_node_t mem_free_t;

How to solve this?

Comment: `#define MEMSIZE (4096ull*1024*1024)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in

```
typedef *free_node_t mem_free_t;
```

which should be

```
typedef free_node_t *mem_free_t;
```

but please do not `typedef` pointers. Also I believe that the suffix `_t` is typically reserved.

Note too that `4096*1024*1024` will not fit a 32-bit variable, whatever it is for, and probably will not multiply as you think it will.